# manipulate form target via javascript

Tags: javascript

I use a function to deliver different variables through a form.

```js
function nav(target,array){
 var arrayLength=array.length;
 if(target===1){
  document.getElementById(10).target='_blank';
 }
 for(var i=0; i<arrayLength; i++){
            document.getElementById(i).value=array[i];
        }
 document.navi.submit();
}
```

```html
<form id=10 action='' method='post' name='navi'>
 <input type='hidden' id=0 name=nav[0] value=''>
 <input type='hidden' id=1 name=nav[1] value=''>
 <input type='hidden' id=2 name=nav[2] value=''>
 <input type='hidden' id=3 name=nav[3] value=''>
 <input type='hidden' id=4 name=nav[4] value=''>
</form>
```

If I set the target=0 it should execute the form on the same page, if 1 it should open a new window.

Everything works fine, but if I close the new window and proceed on the other window and click on a button where the Target=0 it still opens a new window.

Any ideas?

Comment: HTML id attribute values should not start with a number. This seems like a very convoluted way to solve what you are trying to do. Seems almost circular.

Answer (score 0):

The Numbers seem to not be the Problem. I recreated a very simple Version of it, this time without numbers and text instead of.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function nav(target){
   if(target==='outside') document.getElementById('testform').target='_blank';
   document.formtest.submit();
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <form id='testform' name='formtest' action=''>
  <div onclick="nav('inside')">Button1</div>
  <div onclick="nav('outside')">Button2</div>
 </form>
</body>
</HTML>
```

If you click button1 it reloads as intended.

If you click button2 it opens a new window as intended.

If you Close the new window and click again button1 it opens a new window which is not inteded...